# how to set proxy in python 3.x httplib2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, httplib2

The "httplib2" library is working pretty well in both "python 2.x and 3.x" but while using it with proxy setup the 3.x version is not supporting ,please guide me how to add proxy over "httplib2" in "python 3.x" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2/commit/9d1ef6ea3db01107cb88b7bed0b58633802de476) on the httplib2 repo, it seems that the issue has been solved. I'm able to use httplib2 with proxy and python 3.7

Note however that it's not released yet as a pip package on pypi, so you'll need to checkout the master branch from their github repository to get the latest version.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to use [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066009/connect-to-a-server-through-proxy-with-socket-library-python3) library as mention in existing question.

Comment: Is this possible over Python 3.6 ,I don't think so.